# How to run a function in views.py from another Python file

Tags: python, django

So I'm trying to create a script which will run a function in a views.py, but because the function in views.py involves a `request` argument which *needs* a user attribute to work, I'm getting an error.

Here is my external Python code:

```py
import django
import time
from django.http import request
import os, sys

PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))

if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    from os import sys, path
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pcbuilder.settings')
    django.setup()
    sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
    from cpu.views import update

update(request)
```

And here is an excerpt of my views.py:

```py
def update(request):
    current_user = request.user
    #...
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'user'
```

My URLConf:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'pcbuilder.urls'
```

Comment: In this case, "update" is expecting an instance of HttpRequest, you are passing in a module, which is not the same thing as a Class and not the same thing as a properly instantiated Class instance.  Additionally, what you are trying to do may seem reasonable, but it is not the "normal way".  It might help us to know what you are trying to achieve.  Most likely, the solution will be to "refactor". That is, if there is some code logic in that view you want to make use of then extract that portion of logic out to another location. Isolate that logic, perhaps in a model function.  Need more info..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the URLConf.

Comment: `django.http.request` is a _module_, so it makes no sense to pass it to a view function which is expecting an instance of `HttpRequest`.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: But in any case this wouldn't make any sense to do. What would the user be when called from the command?

Comment: @BillHuneke I'm trying to get a python script running in the background which updates my database periodically. Celery requires an installation of a program, which Azure KUDU doesn't allow me doing, and django-cron doesn't seem to work. Nohup might work.

Comment: @heemayl is this what you mean?

Comment: So, what you want to do is refactor. There is business logic in that request handler you want to run periodically. Extract that and make it work in its own function. Test that function.  Now, call that function from your request handler when you have a genuine web request that wants to run that logic.  Similarly, call that function from your external script when you want to access that logic.  Make sense? If not clear, maybe you should post more of your request handler code